# How Do I Make it so Block of Text is Left, Column of Images are Right

Tags: html, css

So right now I have a block of text and images to the right. It looks fine on my PC, but on mobile the images go off the screen and I have to scroll to the right to see all of it. Is there a way to fix this?

PC view (*Blacked out text and image for personal reasons*):

[image: PC]

Mobile View:

[image: Mobile]

As you can see the images go off the the grey background.

Here's what my code currently looks like:

```
<div id="mainContent">
    <div id="images" style="width:20%;float:right;margin:0;padding:0;">
        <img alt="Camp1" src="../images/aA0Va8WQ.jpeg" width="320" height="428" title="Camp1">
        <img alt="Camp2" src="../images/37679145_1817909031657489_8733839330973319168_n.jpg" title="Camp2">
        <img alt="Camp3" src="../images/19428929_122721344992456_2874273194875813888_n.jpg" title="Camp3">
    </div>

    <div id="mainText" style="width:80%;">
        <p>Enter text here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also as a preference I would prefer it so the block of code for the images goes under the text but it's not necessary, it's currently above as I couldn't get this to work otherwise.

Also I'm using the style tags for now before I fix it properly then I will add it to my css file.

Comment: I think the problem is that the div with id "images" is taking 20% width, but the images inside it do not. Try adding the width to the images them selfs and tell me how did it go.

Comment: you forgot to account for the margins that occur on mobile from your image you can set margin and padding to 0 first see what happens also try `#example1 {box-sizing: border-box;}` then try reducing the `80%-20%` to `70%-20%` but best advice will be to use `display: flex;` then if your not for cross browser support use `CSS Grids`

Comment: Tried adding with to the images and tried to use the flex thing earlier couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Flexbox I believe gives the desired result. I removed the floats and the width specs.

```css
#mainContent {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContent">
  <div id="mainText">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="images">
    <img alt="Camp1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" title="Camp1">
    <img alt="Camp2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" title="Camp2">
    <img alt="Camp3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" title="Camp3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! I had use flex before but I also had other stuff inside my mainContent div and it made them go all over the place.